# Copy content from one S3 bucket to another S3 bucket with different keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, copy

I have two S3 buckets with two different set of access and secret keys. Here is the set:

```
Bucket1, Key1, Secret1
```

And

```
Bucket2, Key2, Secret2, Token
```

I am trying to trigger S3-S3 copy via `aws cli` like this:

```
aws s3 cp s3://key1:secret1@Bucket1 s3://key2:secret2@Bucket2
```

I have few questions:

- I am not sure how to specify token for providing write permission to bucket2
- Does `aws cli` allows specifying key and secret as part of S3 Url ?

What would be the best approach to achieve this use case ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To copy a file between Amazon S3 buckets, you must use credentials that have permission to access **both buckets**, or apply a **bucket policy** to the destination bucket that permits the access.

It is not possible to specify two sets of credentials because the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) is only calling a **single AWS API**, which performs the copy 'from' the source bucket directly to the destination bucket. The AWS CLI does not download the object -- it simply tells S3 to copy the object to another bucket (which can even be in a different region).

Therefore, you should **create a bucket policy on the destination bucket** that permits the credentials being used (User or Role) to `PutObject` into the destination bucket.

The policy would be similar to:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-NUMBER:role/ROLE-NAME"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::DESTINATION-BUCKET/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The above is assuming the command is being called from an Amazon EC2 instance with an assigned role. To call from User credentials, use:

```
"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-NUMBER:user/USER-NAME"
```

Comment: Minor (low-level) detail with this: *"it simply tells S3 to copy the object to another bucket."*  Technically, it tells S3 to copy the object *from* (instead of *to*) another bucket, because the API request is always sent to the destination bucket. Then the destination bucket, internally inside S3, fetches the object from the source bucket as specified by `x-amz-copy-source`.

Comment: Ah! Interesting! Yes, the documentation for `aws s3 cp` says *If --source-region is not specified the region of the source will be the same as the region of the destination bucket.* However, I made tests copying from Region-A to Region-B and it worked with both regions as the "calling region". In fact, it even worked with Region-C as the "calling region". So, that parameter doesn't seem to do anything. And `aws s3api copy-object` works fine with any region combination, too.

Comment: FYI, raised a question against the AWS CLI project: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2274 It seems that `--source-region` is not required, but if specified then it will be enforced.