# How to copy s3 bucket from a different account which requires different Access Key ID and Secret Key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to copy some S3 objects from a client. The client sent us the key and secret and I can list the object using the following command.

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=.... AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=.... aws s3 ls s3://bucket/company4/
```

I will need to copy/sync s3://bucket/company4/ (very large) of our client's S3. In this question [Copy content from one S3 bucket to another S3 bucket with different keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40372507/copy-content-from-one-s3-bucket-to-another-s3-bucket-with-different-keys), it mentioned that it can be done by creating a bucket policy on the destination bucket. However, we probably don't have permission to create the bucket policy because we have limited AWS permissions in our company.

I know we can finish the job by copying the external files to local file system first and then upload them to our S3 bucket. Is there a more efficient way to do the work?

Comment: I would spin up an EC2 and do `aws s3 sync s3://... /local/path` and `aws s3 sync /local/path s3://<destination-bucket>`

Comment: Yes, this will do the work. However, there are a large number of big files to sync, so I need to create an EC2 with a lot of storage. Maybe this is still the easiest way to do the work.

Comment: Or attach an efs.

Comment: @Riz EFS is super slow. I would go with the ec2 option.

Comment: You can copy the files from one bucket to another using boto3, with something [like this small example](https://gist.github.com/Q726kbXuN/a42265cdf24dd7e2632a5e57de8e8727)

Comment: You certainly want to add a Bucket Policy to the destination bucket in your own account. The bucket policy should permit `PutObject` and `ListBucket` for the credentials that you are using. You will need to disable S3 Block Public Access to permit the addition of a bucket policy and you will also need to know the ARN of the credentials, which you can get with `aws iam get-user`. Rather than saying "we probably don't have permission to create the bucket policy", I suggest that you try it and see whether it is possible. If not, you should ask your AWS Administrator to do it.